# Exporting PNG files from Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

How can I export a Plotly chart as a image from R using code? (Not using the export button on the chart).

For example, this code from the Plotly site, create this chart:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)
```

[image: plotly chart]

How can I save it as a image?

The official site has [this material](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/) in python, but I didn't find something similar in R.

Comment: Just a remark: You seem to visualize carat by means of dot size, color and the position on the x-axis. This is redundant and may be misleading.

Answer (score 16):

There is an `export` function which allows you to save images without the need to connect to `plotly` servers. You can find it in the [plotly package doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/plotly.pdf):

```
p <- plot_ly(...)
export(p, file = "image.png")
```

You can even change the file type of output by selecting the extension as `.png`, `jpeg` or `.pdf`.

You can also save the image in `html` file which allows you the `plotly` experience like zooming or showing annotations by using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`:

```
p <- plot_ly(...)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, file = "image.html")
```

Comment: export depends on phantomjs as well, I wish it was same as ggplot2 something like
       chartvar <- plot_ly(...)
       doc = addPlot(doc, chart)
Hope, plotly team can fix that.

Comment: Now you can use `orca`, which doesn't depend on phantomjs. Usage is the same as `export`: `orca(p, file = "image.png")`. See https://github.com/plotly/orca for more details.

Comment: just noticed that using `orca` reverts text to Times Roman, so if you specify font type in your plot, text is reverted automatically

Comment: `orca` is depricated as well, we should use `save_image`, which depends on the kaleido package in python, but if you do `?plotly::save_image` it'll walk you through installation instructions

Answer (score 8):

In the [Plotly docs in CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/plotly.pdf) I discovered the function `plotly_IMAGE`.

Here is a example:

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
p <- plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)

plotly_IMAGE(p, width = 500, height = 500, format = "png", scale = 2,
             out_file = "~/desktop/test.png")
```

### UPDATE

plotly_IMAGE works using Plotly server. A local solution is welcome.

Comment: I am getting the following error when using `plotly_IMAGE` as suggested above: `Error in process.image(append_class(resp, "image")) : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401).` What can I do about it?

Comment: @joni you need Internet connection.

Comment: Ok, fixed the the problem: I had to set my authentication credentials via `Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="your_plotly_username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="your_api_key")` The **API key** can be found in ones profile settings [HERE](https://plot.ly/settings/api).

Comment: There is local solution, check my anser.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new, I'm unable to comment so I am posting this as a response. The `export` function is deprecated as of `plotly v4.9.0`. Instead, the `orca` function is the suggested method to export plotly objects as static images. Learn more here: [orca function R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.0/topics/orca)

Answer (score 1):

According to plotly the following should work :

1) Install Orca as described here : https://github.com/plotly/orca

2) You might need to restart your PC

Then run the following code :

There is a export function which allows you to save images without the need to connect to plotly servers. You can find it in the plotly package doc:

```
p <- plot_ly(...)
orca(p, file = "image.png")
```

**Note :** I found giving full path is raising a javascript error. So I just gave filename. The files are being saved in `"C:/Users/user/Documents"` in Windows.

Comment: Notice orca is deprecated in favor of kaleido

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to warn other users, that orca changes text when saved.

from my terminal, I have:

[image]

I specified Corbal (Body) in my plot.

When I saved using `orca(z,width = 8*96, height = 3*96, save_path)`, I got

[image]

when I saved using `export(z, file = save_path )`, I got:

[image]

You can tell that the font family is different. Very annoying