# Exporting PNG files from Plotly in R without internet

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

In this question, [Exporting PNG files from Plotly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635) I asked how to export Plotly plots to disk.

I used the function `plotly_IMAGE`, but later discovered that the function uses the Plotly internet servers.

The question is, now that Plotly JavaScript is local, how can I create a png local file without internet?

I tried this code, without success:

```
library(plotly)
png(filename = "test.png")
plot_ly(x = 1:10)
dev.off()
```

The idea is to make it programaticaly, without click on export button over the chart.

Answer (score 5):

They've added a new `export` function to the `plotly` package. But to my knowledge it does the same thing as @MLavoie's answer suggests. Usage:

```
p <- plot_ly(...)
export(p, file = "test.png")
```

Comment: This is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You will to need install Phantom (http://phantomjs.org/download.html) which is quite easy and you can try this:

```
library(plotly)
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)

m <- plot_ly(x = 1:10)
saveWidget(as.widget(m), "temp.html")
webshot("temp.html", file = "test.png",
        cliprect = "viewport")
```

you will find *temp.html* and *temp.png* in your working directory.

Comment: I have downloaded phantomjs. But when I am running the above script I get the following error: `Error in find_phantom() : 
  PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.` Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you have dowloaded it, but did you install it?

Comment: I doubleclicked on the `phantomjs` file in `bin`directory and terminal opened reading: `Last login: Mon May 30 10:47:54 on ttys001
/Users/Jonathan/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs ; exit;
JonathasMacBook:~ Jonathan$ /Users/Jonathan/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs ; exit;
phantomjs> `

Comment: I was on a Mac and I don't remember having issues

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I do have macports on my laptop. phantoms was stored under macports.