# R: Plotly package error in downloading png

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am using the plotly package to create plots in my shiny app but I am having trouble downloading these plots. Because this is for a shiny app, I want it to be interactive and not hardcoded.

Code:

```
library(plotly)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:100), y = rnorm(1:100))
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
plotly_build(p)
```

sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_3.6.0         ggplot2_2.1.0        BiocInstaller_1.23.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.6      tidyr_0.5.1      assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.9     grid_3.3.0       plyr_1.8.4       R6_2.1.2         jsonlite_1.0    
 [9] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     httr_1.2.1       viridis_0.3.4    labeling_0.3     tools_3.3.0      htmlwidgets_0.6 
[17] munsell_0.4.3    yaml_2.1.13      rsconnect_0.4.3  base64enc_0.1-3  colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3.5  gridExtra_2.2.1  tibble_1.1
```

I am having trouble downloading the plot. When I click on the camera on the top right toolbar in the plotly graph, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I am having this problem in the Rstudio Viewer pane, Safari and Chrome.  How can I circumvent this problem and download the plot?

Comment: Have you tried the option mentioned by Murta here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r

Comment: @Pj_ Forgot to add a very important detail that I am using this in a shiny app and do not want to hardcode anything. The user should be able to download the plot which is why I wanted the inbuilt functionality to work.

Comment: @Pj_ can you move your comment to answer so I can accept it? installing the developmental version worked. `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your `plotly` package should do the trick.
 http://community.plot.ly/t/download-png-not-working-in-r-shiny/1574/3