# Exporting PNG files from Plotly in R (on linux)

Tags: r, linux, shiny, png, plotly

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) solutions to export a png file from `plot_ly` in `R`.

These are working on windows machine :

```
DF = structure(list(Sector = c("0-N", "1-NNE", "2-ENE", "3-E", "4-ESE", 
"5-SSE", "6-S", "7-SSW", "8-WSW", "9-W", "10-WNW", "11-NNW"), 
    A_parameter = c(4.84, 5.04, 5.05, 4.7, 4.41, 4.66, 5.76, 
    7.44, 6.92, 4.87, 4.39, 4.13), k_Parameter = c(2.24, 2.271, 
    2.115, 1.959, 1.779, 1.943, 2.01, 2.393, 2.326, 1.971, 1.908, 
    1.904), frequency = c(0.057, 0.08, 0.086, 0.071, 0.05, 0.041, 
    0.071, 0.178, 0.182, 0.089, 0.051, 0.045), mean_WS = c(4.287, 
    4.464, 4.473, 4.167, 3.924, 4.132, 5.104, 6.595, 6.131, 4.317, 
    3.895, 3.665)), .Names = c("Sector", "A_parameter", "k_Parameter", 
"frequency", "mean_WS"), row.names = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), class = "data.frame")

p <- plot_ly(DF, r = ~(DF$frequency*DF$mean_WS), t = ~DF$Sector) %>% add_area()
export(p, file = "C:/Users/philip/Desktop/dashboard/www/L1.png")
```

or using :

```
t=layout(p, radialaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"), orientation = 270)
saveWidget(plotly::as_widget(t), "C:/Users/philip/Desktop/dashboard/www/temp.html")
 webshot("C:/Users/philip/Desktop/dashboard/www/temp.html", 
                file = "C:/Users/philip/Desktop/dashboard/www/L1.png",
                cliprect = "viewport")
```

But when I try the same thing on Linux it does not work :

```
p <- plot_ly(DF, r = ~(DF$frequency*DF$mean_WS), t = ~DF$Sector) %>% add_area()
export(p, file = "/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/L1.png")
```

It doesn't return an error but the png file is blank.
The same results when I try :

```
t=layout(p, radialaxis = list(ticksuffix = "%"), orientation = 270)
        saveWidget(plotly::as_widget(t), "/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/temp.html")
        webshot("/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/temp.html", 
                file = "/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/L1.png",
                cliprect = "viewport")
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: @hrbrmstr do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file directly, or only within your Shiny app? If the latter, have you set the file permissions on `L1.png`?

Comment: @BrianStamper I have tried both ! In shiny it returns error , and when I run it as you see here, `L1.png` is just a blank white page.

Comment: What is the error you get in Shiny?

Comment: @BrianStamper, in shiny, I try to resize the image by : `p=image_resize(image_trim(image_read("/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/L1.png")),"800x")
` and since the `L1.png` is empty I'm getting this error : `Error in magick_image_trim(image, fuzz) :
  Magick: geometry does not contain image `/srv/shiny-server/S3/PCE/www/L1.png' @ warning/attribute.c/GetImageBoundingBox/247
`

Comment: The error does suggest you are producing an empty image. As to why I do not know, sorry. A couple thoughts come to mind - why produce static images with plotly when you can have plotly dynamically render them in the app? And why resize the image when you can do so with CSS? But these questions are out of scope here.

Comment: @BrianStamper I need to put this image in a report ! that's why I need a static one .