# Export Plotly in R syntax

Tags: r, export, plotly

So I have a lot of plotly heatmaps that I need to export to .png format. I have searched and found the `export` function. However when used it brings up an error about `webshot`.

Here is an example of the kind of plots I am exporting (I have 1111 of these plots):

```
p <- plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap")
```

When I try the `export(p, file = "plot11.png")` command I get error:

```
Could not load file:///datatwo/13483885$/GCA%20Capstone/plotly28b83ffb3228.html
Error in webshot::webshot(f, file, ...) :
webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

What should I do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: u have assigned the plot but not saved in any local storage right?

Answer (score 0):

with `processx` package it can be done,

```
if (!require("processx")) install.packages("processx")
orca(p, "plot11.png") ##orca is the replace of export function
```

if u have plot_ly account u can easily export

```
Sys.setenv("plotly_username" = "YOUR USER NAME")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key" = "YOUR API KEY")
plotly_IMAGE(p, format = "png", out_file = "output.png")
```

[sample ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r)

Comment: Yes I have seen this example on the plotly documentation however when I run the `orca` command you specified it returns

`Error in orca(plots[[100]], "plot100.png") :`
`could not find function "orca"`

Comment: Also I have created a plot_ly free account, but when I go to my settings to find my API key it just shows 10 dots, like a password when logging into a computer. How do I get to the actual digits behind these dots?