# R: Is it possible to insert an "html file" into a MS Word Document/MS Powerpoint (Plotly)

Tags: html, r, plotly, data-visualization, powerpoint

I am using the R programming language. I am interested in seeing if it is somehow possible to take an html file (generated using the "plotly" library) and then insert that file into a MS Powerpoint slideshow.

I was looking at other stackoverflow questions where similar things were attempted: [Exporting PNG files from Plotly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r)

Suppose I generate this simple, interactive plot using plotly in R:

```
library(plotly)

x <- rnorm(100,10,10)
color <- rnorm(100, 2,1)
frame = data.frame(x,color)

p = plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", data = frame, x = ~x, y = " ", color = ~color )
```

Using the "htmlwidget" library, I can save the object "p" as an html file. But is there a way to insert this object "p" into a MS Powerpoint presentation? Preferably, an offline way that does not use the internet or requires any additional software to be installed?

I tried using the "insert html" functionality in MS Powerpoint, but this just produces a "grey square" that doesn't load when you play the presentation.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem like a simple thing to do in powerpoint and offline. You can do it if you make the presentation in something like `xaringan`. You might be able to get an addin for powerpoint to embed an iframe. Did you see this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-any-way-to-keep-the-hovering-aspect-of-ggplotly-in-a-ppt-file/7978

Comment: thank you for your reply! this is what i had thought....