# R refuses to write image to disk

Tags: r, image, plot, plotly

I have a simple R timeseries plot created with ts_plot from TSStudio like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(TSstudio)

`standard-data` <- c(1,2,3,4)

png("test.png")
ts_plot(as.ts(`standard-data`), title = "Foo", Xtitle = "Rounds", Ytitle = "Nanos")
dev.off()
```

In RStudio or in Intellij with plugin, it pops up the appropriate graph, but does not write anything to disk

If I close both and run it via R directly in my shell, I still don't get any test.png file.

I've found answers suggesting using `savePlot()` and answers suggesting `print()`ing the result, but none of those things seem to get me a file on disk.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

Comment: Nope, and that print suggestion is what I meant by answers suggesting `print()`ing the result  (the `ts_plotResult <-` was left over from `print(ts_plotResult)` that I removed before pasting in)

Comment: Fake data provided :) the data isn't an issue. Even with this, I can run the line in R studio and get a graph, but this file fails to write a PNG no matter where I run it.

Comment: I've just noticed that subbing in ts.plot does work, this may be a TSStudio bug.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question; I think the issue might be caused by the `ts_plot()` function using a plotly backend; do you get a png file using `plotly::export(ts_plot(as.ts(\`standard-data\`), title = "Foo", Xtitle = "Rounds", Ytitle = "Nanos"))`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r for alternative solutions, or just use `ts.plot()` as you discovered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a ts_plot and therefore TSStudio thing inherited from their use of Plotly, which has R and Python flavors (the latter leveraged by R flavor). There has evidently been a LOT of churn when it comes to image creation infrastructure for plotly. What finally worked:

```
pip install kaleido
pip install plotly
```

then

```
install.packages("reticulate")
```

and changing the above to use:

```
ts_plotResult <- ts_plot(as.ts(`standard-data`), title = "Foo", Xtitle = "Rounds", Ytitle = "Nanos")
plotly::save_image(ts_plotResult,"test.png")
```

Thanks to @jared_mamrot for the pointer, though his link leads to a page that is 99% deprecated churn one comment on one answer there mentioned plotly::save_image

Misinformation that one must discard:

- `plotly::export()` --> deprecated, use orca instead. This apparently generated a web page, and then took a screenshot of that with a javascript utility, but something in the stack for that depends on an old version of OpenSSL not supported in Ubuntu 22... this route seemed to partly work as I could see a temporary .html file flash by, but ended with: `140025987807168:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(libproviders.so): libproviders.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
- `orca()` --> requires external server of some sort, but also deprecated, use plotly::save_image() instead
- references to `plotly_IMAGE()` apparently something relating to some sort of plotly server. Not helpful for simple R usage.